# Is it true that python 2.7 will die soon?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i've heard that python 2.7 will be removed or something like that. And i just starter so i'm confused if i should start with python 2.7 or the newest one 3.7?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a Google search question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, https://pythonclock.org/

> Python 2.7 [will not be maintained past 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/).

---

Until you discover an explicit reason otherwise, use the current stable versions of all software and hardware dependencies to start a project. Some software (e.g. Node.js or browsers) have special releases on the long term support track (LTS), but Python versions should be all equal in this regard, so 3.7 is a good choice in 2019.

An explicit reason might be integration with existing libraries (that do not work on current version and cannot be updated or replaced), or other business reasons.